# Consider the parametric curve: $x=6\cos^3(t), y=6\sin^3(t)$, write it in cartesian form.

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, parametric

> Consider the parametric curve: $$x=6\cos^3(t), y=6\sin^3(t)$$ Write it in Cartesian form.

I am really struggling with the solution for this. I've been trying to find $t$ from $x$, and then plugging that into $y$, but it ends up being too complicated.

It is asked to be put in the form $F(x,y)=c$, for some function $F,$ and some constant $c$.

Any help at all would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Could you check what you wrote in the title?  You have defined $x$ twice.

Comment: yes my bad, one of the x's is supposed to be y=6sin^3(t)

Answer (score 2):

solving for $t,$ you get $$\cos t = \left(\frac x6\right)^{1/3} , \, \sin t = \left(\frac y6\right)^{1/3}  $$ now use the fact $$\sin^2 t + \cos ^2 t = 1 \to \left(\frac x6\right)^{2/3} + \left(\frac y6\right)^{2/3} = 1$$

Comment: Greatly appreciated, thankyou.

Comment: @AidanLeith, you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

From $$x=6\cos^3(t), y=6\sin^3(t)$$ we get $$\cos^2t=\left(\frac{x}{6}\right)^{2/3}$$ and $$\sin^2t=\left(\frac{y}{6}\right)^{2/3}$$
From the Pythagorean identity $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$ then we get
$$\left(\frac{x}{6}\right)^{2/3}+\left(\frac{y}{6}\right)^{2/3}=1$$ or $$x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=6^{2/3}$$

This is a very useful technique for finding the Cartesian form of a parametric curve given in terms of sines and cosines (etc), namely use some sort of trigonometric identity to relate the sines and cosines and then substitute your $x$s and $y$s.

Comment: Greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: no worries! you should choose a particular answer you want to accept, not necessarily mine but whichever you found answered your question the best :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem was $x=6\cos^3 t,y=6\sin^3t$.
Write $\cos^2t$ as a function of $x$, and $\sin^2t$ as a function of $y$.

Comment: Yes it was supposed to be that, thank you :)

Comment: I get cos^2(t)=x/6cos(t), and sin^2(t)=y/6sin(t), but that still doesn't eliminate to parameter, do I still do x/6cos(t) + y/6sin(t) = 1, or am I missing something?